# How to specify millisecond timeouts in JDBC calls to MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, tomcat, jdbc

In developing a fast MySQL Java application, how can I specify timeouts in milliseconds when performing the following operations:

1. getting a connection from the connection pool
2. executing a query

I am unable to find the answer to (1) in the MySQL documentation on [Connection Pooling with Connector/J.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html)

I did find the [maxWait](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes) connection pool attribute in Tomcat's connection pool that allows for specifying a timeout in milliseconds as a pool attribute. If the getConnection operation takes more than maxWait time then a timeout exception is raised.

Is the use of [Tomcat connection pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) the only option for my first requirement?

Regarding the second requirement of specifying a query timeout, the JDBC document has the method [setQueryTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)) on the Statement object. But this takes the timeout value in seconds (an integer value). How can my requirement of specifying timeout in milliseconds be met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library doesn't have builtin support for timeouts, you can always use an `ExecutorService` and a `Future` to emulate a timeout:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private DataSource dataSource;

public void doSomething() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException, SQLException {
    Connection connection =
            executor.submit(() -> dataSource.getConnection()).get(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = executor.submit(() -> stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM blah"))
                .get(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            // Do something with result set
        }
    }
}
```

This will leave threads in the threadpool running (trying to complete the `getConnection` or the query) but you can respond within a set time to your user / caller.

Comment: Hi @ErwinBolwidt, thank you for your good suggestion. Is there a performance impact of forwarding the request and getting the response from a thread in threadpool? Also, if one wanted to abort the operation upon timeout, can the [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) method of the returned Future object be used?